# pandas DataFrame upsert to SQLite

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, sqlalchemy, upsert

All I want is a simple Upsert from the DataFrame to  SQLite. However, since pd.to_sql() does not have Upsert, I had to implement it with SQLAlchemy instead.

SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE test (col1 INTEGER, col2 text, col3 REAL, PRIMARY KEY(col1, col2));
```

python:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Table
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base

def test_upsert():
    
    df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':1, 'col2':'a', 'col3':1.5}, index=[0])
    
    sql_url = 'sqlite:///testDB.db'
    table = 'test'
    engine = create_engine(sql_url)
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        base = automap_base()
        base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
        target_table = Table(table, base.metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)            
        stmt = insert(target_table).values(df.to_dict(orient='records'))
        update_dict = {c.name: c for c in stmt.excluded if not c.primary_key}
        conn.execute(stmt.on_conflict_do_update(constraint=f'{table}_pkey', set_=update_dict))
```

The script above works with Postgres previously but it keeps giving me the error when used with SQLite.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "ON": syntax error
[SQL: INSERT INTO test (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ON CONFLICT (test_pkey) DO UPDATE SET col3 = excluded.col3]
[parameters: (1, 'a', 1.5)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong, or if there's any better solution since it seems like a very common operation.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How many records are you trying to do this with?

Comment: Actually, can you even do ON CONFLICT for a compound key when only a single value is duplicated?

Comment: @roganjosh each DataFrame has a different number of rows. Thanks